# Google Calendar API err not found

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar to get my calendar events.Google Calendar API tutorial is [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js).

All works well I can get my event by setting the `calendarId:'primary'`.

There are also some other calendars besides 'primary' in my calendar, like holidays. Then I think I should change the `calendarId` to others to get the events, but I got error:

```
Error: Not Found
```

The code is like below: `zh_cn.china#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com` this `calendarId` doesn't work,

```
calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    //calendarId: 'zh_cn.china#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 50,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  }, (err, {data}) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const events = data.items;
    if (events.length) {
      console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
      events.map((event, i) => {
        const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    }
  });
```

I also tried to get all the calendarIds from my account:

```
   calendar.calendarList.list({
    maxResults: 100
  },function (err, result) {
    console.log(result.data.items);
  })
```

The result is like:

```
 [{ kind: 'calendar#calendarListEntry',
    etag: '"1530087829067000"',
    id: 'zh_cn.china#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
    summary: '中国节假日',
    timeZone: 'Asia/Shanghai',
    colorId: '12',
    backgroundColor: '#fad165',
    foregroundColor: '#000000',
    accessRole: 'reader',
    defaultReminders: [],
    conferenceProperties: { allowedConferenceSolutionTypes: [Array] } ]
```

Looks like the calendarId is correct.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the way is:

```
calendarId: encodeURIComponent(id)
```